# AngularJS - transform input value and have the view reflect changes made

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When a user inputs text in one of my inputs I want to

1. remove all whitespace
2. make entered text lowercase
3. have the view input value changed to reflect above changes

I wrote a little directive to deal with lowercase and it looks good, but works like crap

```
angular.module("app").directive "toLowercase", function()
{
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel)
        {
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue)
            {
                var val = (viewValue || "").toLowerCase();
                element.val(val);
                return val;
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function()
            {
                return ngModel.$modelValue.toLowerCase();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Usage demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tr2jhb8t/
It seems to have issues with whitespace and the cursor works funky in the input-field (because I replace the value I reckon).

Anyone have done anything like this?

Comment: What's the issue with whitespace? I tried - it worked fine.

Comment: Pressing space immediately after entering upper case text doesn't seem to work at all but it might be a local issue if you're not experiencing it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if you just make a $scope function that is triggered on ng-keyup and return the event when they key is not spacebar and change characters to lower case if needed ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the reformat-function `onblur` cause `ngModel` will trigger on each keydown

see https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/directive/ngBlur